# adding another select

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(a.aircraft) as total
    , a.aircraft
    , b.fullname AS aircraft_name 
FROM db_pireps AS a 
JOIN db_aircraft AS b ON a.aircraft = b.id 
WHERE pilotid = {$pilotid}
GROUP BY aircraft 
ORDER BY total DESC 
LIMIT 6
```

I have this query, however I am trying to add `b.registration AS reg` but my attempts seem to be failing, as I don't know how to put another SELECT within that query.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Could you show the query that's getting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a comma:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(a.aircraft) as total,
  a.aircraft,
  b.fullname AS aircraft_name,
  b.registration AS reg
FROM db_pireps AS a JOIN db_aircraft AS b 
  ON a.aircraft = b.id WHERE pilotid = {$pilotid}
GROUP BY aircraft ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 6
```

Comment: You learn something new everyday, thanks. I never knew you could use a comma.

Comment: @zzwyb89: Really?  Did you not read the rest of the query?  Did you not write that query to start with?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(a.aircraft) as total, a.aircraft, b.fullname AS aircraft_name, b.registration AS reg
FROM db_pireps AS a JOIN db_aircraft AS b ON a.aircraft = b.id 
WHERE a.pilotid = {$pilotid}
GROUP BY a.aircraft 
ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 6
```

Tip: To avoid problem with columns naming, if you use alias for table name, use the alias on all columns that you are using in the query.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your Question, but I think this should work:

```
$aircraft_query = "SELECT COUNT(a.aircraft) as total, a.aircraft, b.fullname AS aircraft_name, b.registration AS reg 
                  FROM db_pireps AS a JOIN db_aircraft AS b ON a.aircraft = b.id 
                  WHERE pilotid = {$pilotid}
                  GROUP BY aircraft 
                  ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 6";
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add column b.registration and give it alias as reg. see below. Its the same as you have done count

```
SELECT COUNT(a.aircraft) as total, a.aircraft, b.fullname AS aircraft_name, b.registration   AS reg
FROM db_pireps AS a JOIN db_aircraft AS b ON a.aircraft = b.id 
WHERE pilotid = {$pilotid}
GROUP BY a.aircraft 
 ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 6
```